# Heroku .net app on tv browser doesn't works (it does on mobile and PC)

Tags: .net, angular, heroku, smart-tv

I deployed .net core+angular app on heroku. It works perfectly on mobile and PC. But part of app is used on tv browser (it displays images and videos, which you upload in the other part of the app). But I can't see anything on the screen (no bad request, no error) it even displays correct favicon, but content is blank white. What could be the problem?